# Exclude directories from flake8 tests when it's run through colcon?

Tags: python, testing, ros2, flake8, colcon

## Question

I tried to build a simple ROS2 package using colcon, but I struggle to exclude directories from the flake8 tests launched with `colcon test-result` (namely the `install` and `build` directories), even after excluding them in my setup.cfg file.

However, when I run `flake8 ./` on my terminal at the root of my package, it effectively excludes them. So I guess flake8 is not reading my setup.cfg file when it's run through `colcon test-result`, but I'd like to stick with colcon for my testing because it's more convenient.

My ROS2 package looks like this:

```
├── dummy_pkg
│   ├── dummy_pkg
│   │   ├── main.py
├── build
├── test
│   ├── test_flake8.py
│   ├── test_pep257.py
│   ├── test_copyright.py    
├── install
├── logs
├── resource
├── setup.py
├── setup.cfg
└── package.xml
```

My setup.cgf file, like this:

```
[flake8]
exclude =
    .git,
    __pycache__,
    build,
    dist,
    install
    test
[develop]
script_dir=$base/lib/test_pkg
[install]
install_scripts=$base/lib/test_pkg
```

Any idea how to solve this?

## What I've tried

I followed these steps to create the package:

- I created an empty ROS2 package using `ros2 pkg create dummy_pkg` (with ament-python as build-type). I created a simple main.py that just prints something and I setup the entry point to `main` of main.py in package.xml. After that, I run `colcon build --symlink-install` in my package root, which creates the tree structure as shown above.

I can now run it using `ros2 run dummy_pkg main` and it outputs the correct thing.

- I then add these lines to setup.cfg:

```
[flake8]
exclude =
    .git,
    __pycache__,
    build,
    dist,
    install
    test
[develop]
script_dir=$base/lib/test_pkg
[install]
install_scripts=$base/lib/test_pkg
```

- After running `colcon build --symlink-install` again, I run `colcon test-result --verbose` which I expected to output only tests on my source files. However, here's what it outputs:

```
build/dummy_pkg/pytest.xml: 3 tests, 0 errors, 1 failure, 1 skipped
- dummy_pkg.test.test_flake8 test_flake8
  <<< failure message
    AssertionError: Found 6 code style errors / warnings:
      ./install/_local_setup_util_sh.py:14:100: E501 line too long (109 > 99 characters)
      ./install/_local_setup_util_sh.py:15:100: E501 line too long (124 > 99 characters)
      ./install/_local_setup_util_sh.py:16:100: E501 line too long (125 > 99 characters)
      ./build/dummy_pkg/build/lib/dummy_pkg/run.py:2:24: W292 no newline at end of file
      ./build/dummy_pkg/prefix_override/sitecustomize.py:3:100: E501 line too long (104 > 99 characters)
    assert 1 == 0
  >>>

Summary: 3 tests, 0 errors, 1 failure, 1 skipped
```

It still performs a flake8 test on the `install` and `build` directories..

Comment: what's in your `test.test_flake8` ?

Comment: @anthonysottile It's a flake8 test shipped with ROS2. You can find it here: https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/4370b2b829946cd8c5ec5a76cbb3bb6a70c95e97/launch/test/test_flake8.py

Comment: as I suspected -- it's not flake8 but someone's reimagination of flake8: https://github.com/ament/ament_lint/blob/rolling/ament_flake8/ament_flake8/main.py

Comment: indeed, thank you! That's why it wasn't reading my cfg file.